# MVC C# Best approach - session variable

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, session-variables

I have a Details and Edit page from where the user can send out an email by clicking on a email hyperlink.

When they click on the Details or Edit page hyperlink, I go to the controller which opens up an email that the user can edit.

On submit of the email, I go to the [httppost].

On the httppost actionresult, I need to use the return RedirectToAction in order to redirect the user back to either the Edit or Details page from where they started from.

I was thinking of keeping this information in a session variable as to where the user originated from:

```
   Session["Originated"] = "Edit";
```

or

```
   Session["Originated"] = "Details";
```

Or is there a better way to keep track of this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe add route parameter? For example /Email/Create?originated=Edit. It will keep all your stuff sessionless.

Example:
In View

```
 @Html.ActionLink("Create email", "Create", "Email", new { originated = "Edit" }, null)
```

In Action

```
public ActionResult Create(string originated)
{
...
}
```

Comment: I would agree, and state that in most cases you should avoid Session unless you have a value used globally.

Comment: How do I add a route parameter

Comment: I'm assuming your Controller is called Email and your action is called Create.  If that's the case you would do this:   public ActionResult Create(string originated) { } in your Email controller.

Comment: @Alexey - I see what you mean but on [HttpPost] this is where I need to get the value of originated but seems like it is gone. I do not have control  of the view

Comment: Embed it into view model. Add property like Origin. And in GET - populate your view model with it, and in view you can add hidden input @Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.Origin) and on POST retrive it =)